# qserialport data missing while reading from port but returns 9 bytes available

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtserialport, qextserialport

While reading from the port using the function readdata of `qextserialport` class data loss happens

For example `serialobj->bytesavailable` returns 9 bytes but while `serialobj->readData` returns only two characters from pic microcontroller

Comment: In the readData()'s doc, I have seen that readData return an integer. (Reads up to maxSize bytes from the device into data, and returns the number of bytes read or -1 if an error occurred.). Which value do you have ?

Comment: I have the total number of bytes received,

Comment: char arr_cReadbuffer[1024];
int nBytesAvailable = m_serialportCoProcessor->bytesAvailable();
qDebug()<<"\r\n available bytes: "<<nBytesAvailable;
if ( nBytesAvailable > 0 ) {
/* read the available bytes */
int nBytesReceived = m_serialportCoProcessor->readData(arr_cReadbuffer,nBytesAvailable);
qDebug()<<"\r\n Bytes Received"<<nBytesReceived<<arr_cReadbuffer;




"available bytes: 9" 

Bytes Received 9 ^MK1 

Only 4 characters available at the time of reading

Comment: You should edit your post, add your code between appropriate tag because it's unreadable.

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59959-Serial-read-misses-to-read-data-from-the-serial-port?p=265901#post265901

Comment: @Martin I have posted the same in qtcentre can you refer the code from the above link

Comment: @TeamSwatkats, you did not publish the code on Qt Center as well. It is hard to answer such a questions without code samples.

Comment: @Tanuki at qtcentre I have published the code which is the first question in the thread

Comment: As I saw your program output: you have 9 bytes available and you have read 9 bytes. Where did you get the idea that you have only 4 bytes available? First 9 bytes in your buffer is exactly what you have read from your serial port.

Comment: "available bytes: 9" 

 Bytes Received 9 ^MK1 

 Data length 4

Comment: Try to check all bytes. Byte 5 might be 0. Try to print each byte you get.

Comment: Try this to get byte values as hex: std::ostringstream oss; for (auto i = 0; i < nBytesReceived; i++) oss << "0x" << std::hex << int(arr_cReadbuffer[i]) << " ";

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the comments, you're trying to print out the received bytes to the console. Obviously, some of the bytes you attempt to print out are not printable and produce no visual output.

Perhaps you want to see the values of the bytes in hexadecimal base:

```
qDebug() << serialObj->readData().toHex();
```

Comment: @TeamSwatkats Those bytes are not printable, so printing them produces no visible output.

Comment: how can i receive all the bytes is there any means

Comment: @TeamSwatkats You have received the bytes. They are there. You just can't see them because they are not printable. What's so hard to understand about it? Not all bytes correspond to printable characters.